# eclipse PDT installation error

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-pdt

tried to download eclipse PDT plugin and i have got this error

```
An error occurred while installing the items
session context was:(profile=DefaultProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Install, operand=null --> [R]org.eclipse.rcp.configuration_root.win32.win32.x86_64 1.0.0.v20140117-0610, action=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.natives.actions.ChmodAction).
The action chmod failed - file C:\Users\hadi\Desktop\work\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\eclipse\eclipse.exe does not exist
```

what is the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's related to some administration rights,, try to run eclipse as an administrator